# Design service on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In google cloud platform i want to write one application that will take http request , hit apis in chain and then show a template based on the response received from the api and populate them with data received from apis . There are many templates .

What is the best way to design on GCP considering the below.
1. The application will received huge traffic.
2. Some apis will return dynamic urls that template needs.

I was thinking of wrinting in java and putting that on Kubernetes , that will manage the traffic . But what should be the choice of database to be used ?
The data is mostly key value pairs and should be highly available , in case it is down some backup should be there

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Kubernetes is one option, something else that you may want to consider to handle huge app traffic is [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) (GAE), since you mentioned Java development you can use the [GAE Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/) environment which is easy to build, deploy and runs reliably even under heavy load (fully managed).

You may want to consider using [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/) since based on your description, it is the best fit for the application needs (NoSQL database and automatically handles sharding and replication). You can also use the [diagram](https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/) to choose the best storage option.